# Vuejs: How to remove a param in a link

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following links:

```
  http://example.com/post?st=1&plt=123&number=1
  http://example.com/post?st=1&plt=[exp]&number=1
  http://example.com/post/view/12?ex=1&plt=123
  http://example.com/post/edit/12?ex=1&test=2&plt=[exp]
```

For example, I have links like above. Now I want to remove the param `&plt=` from the link, how to do it.
Everyone please give me your opinion. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add what you have tried so far? This seems like a pure Javascript question unless you are using the vue router. Please update your question with this info.

Comment: A simple `string.replace()` with RegExp should do the trick, but I too would like to know what you've tried so far, before giving the answear.

Comment: You could make another `$router.push` with the param you don't want to be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are looking for is simply removing the contents of `&plt=`, alongside with is value, doing this should work:

```js
const link = 'http://example.com/post?st=1&plt=123&number=1'
const regex = /(&plt=.+?(?=&))|(&plt=.*)/gi

const replacedString = link.replace(regex, '')
// Expected Output: 'http://example.com/post?st=1&number=1'
```

The RegEx search for the `&plt=`, until it finds a `&` meaning it has more parameters after. If it doesn't have a `&` it takes all the string until the end. And then the `replace()`, replaces the content found with nothing.

Comment: Thank @Mael. 
I did it your way, and tested with a link: `http://example.com/post?st=1&plt=123&test=abc&number=1` --> result : `http://example.com/post?st=1&number=1` .. It lost the param `&test=abc` . Can you fix it for me. Thank you

Comment: @Miedkes my approach is not working?

Comment: @kissu Thank you for your reply. But I applied it not working. Can you give me a separate answer? I really do not know vuejs yet.

Comment: @Miedkes mind sharing what you already tried with Vue?

Comment: @Miedkes adjusted the answear so it will work with subsequent parameters